# PhoneGap Access Origin Restrictions Don't Work

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm developing an iOS app using Cordova 3.3.0.  In my config.xml, I have the following:

`<access origin="https://*.kidsintouch.com" />`

Theoretically, that should stop my app from accessing any resources that try to load outside that domain.

However, when I run the app in the simulator or on device via Xcode, I can access images from any domain.

The PhoneGap docs say :

> Unlike the Android platform noted above, navigating to non-whitelisted domains via href hyperlink on iOS prevents the page from opening at all.

However, I'm still able to put an external link on a page in the app and click on it.

When I run the app in Xcode, I see the following console output:

`2014-01-02 06:47:16.469 Kids In Touch[10454:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-01-02 06:47:16.480 Kids In Touch[10454:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-01-02 06:47:17.276 Kids In Touch[10454:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-01-02 06:47:18.157 Kids In Touch[10454:60b] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/8DBB3EE2-A33D-4523-A51F-B72AJ21E5338/Kids%20In%20Touch.app/www/index.html#/intro
2014-01-02 06:47:19.629 Kids In Touch[10454:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.`

The `Unlimited access to network resources` clearly shows something is wrong. When I click on a bogus link to Google I put in the app, the console displays:

`2014-01-02 06:47:20.755 Kids In Touch[10454:60b] Finished load of: https://www.google.com/`

So clearly my `access origin` restriction is not actually restricting anything.

Is there something I am doing wrong?  How do I prevent my app from accessing any resources outside the domain I've provided?

Thanks

Comment: Refer this- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: @Suhas I referenced the PhoneGap 3.3.0 documentation already.  I am configured according to those docs.  It still does not work.  The docs you reference are quite old and no longer relevant (i think).

Comment: You have tried subdomains='false' ?

Comment: @Suhas For iOS, subdomains are no longer a valid setting.  See PhoneGap 3.3.0 documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem with this.  For some reason, the config.xml file produced by `cordova build ios` is NOT the same as I have in my `www` folder.

There seems to be some default info in it THEN my real info from `www/config.xml` is appended to it.  At the top of the default config info is `<access origin="*" />`.

So, the app is allowed all access.

I tried completely blowing out the existing config.xml by running `cordova platform remove ios` and then rerunning `cordova build ios`.  This did not work.  Each time I build, some default stuff is prepended to my real config.xml.

Cure for now until I dig deeper is to manual edit the config.xml after every build.  When I do this and try to access a domain not configured with `access origin`, I get:

`ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://0.0.0.0:8080/accounts'`

So, whitelisting works properly, but I've got a wonky build process to resolve.

UPDATE : There is a file `platforms/ios/cordova/defaults.xml` that contains the default settings for an XML file.  It has the `access origin *` in it.  I deleted that and a few other settings and can now build properly respecting the config.xml in my www folder.

All is well.  Strange that these defaults get put into my final config.xml.

Comment: I ran into this for iOS too on version 3.1.0.  Other searching led me to this (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/211) which was closed as won't fix.

In any case, it seems the entries in `defaults.xml` are not overridden  by your `www/config.xml` entries (at least for iOS).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. As an alternative to deleting the defaults, you can ensure that your  tags are placed immediately after the  tag in the config.xml.